# Can a local object live entirely in a hardware register in C++?

Tags: c++

In C++ is it possible for the compiler to optimize code so that a local object instance will live entirely in registers, instead of being allocated in the stack?

For instance, with this code:

```cpp
#include <inttypes.h>

class int24_t {
    int32_t val;
public:
    int24_t(int32_t v = 0) { val = v & 0xffffff; }
    int24_t add(int24_t v) { return int24_t(val + v.val); }
};

int24_t add_two_int24(int24_t a, int24_t b)
{
    return a.add(b);
}
```

There are no virtual functions, nor any other extra data, making “`val`” effectively the only data stored in memory for this object, so is it possible that the compiler will generate assembly like:

```
push ebp
mov  ebp, esp
mov  eax, [ebp+8]
add  eax, [ebp+12]
and  eax, 0x00ffffff
pop  ebp
ret
```

Instead of allocating a space in the stack for the object?

**Edit**:

It is possible. For example, `gcc -march=native -O2 -c` in my computer  (x64_64) generates this code:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <add_two_int24(int24_t, int24_t)>:
   0:   8d 04 37                lea    (%rdi,%rsi,1),%eax
   3:   25 ff ff ff 00          and    $0xffffff,%eax
   8:   c3                      retq
```

Comment: Pretty easy to check yourself using GCC's `-S` flag.

Comment: your code can't compile as there are a lot of problems, like undefined `int_t` type, `a` is not a class, and `get` function doesn't have a return type. Fixing all those things you can see the assembly output easily https://goo.gl/6sHSK5 there's no need for push pop like your version

Comment: Generally compilers will only put stuff in the registers when they see a benefit. For instance, when variable is used in a loop. Stuff that is only accessed once during lifetime of the function is unlikely to go into the register.

Comment: phuclv, I corrected my code, now I think it really exemplifies my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes--not only possible, but fairly common for this to happen (especially for things like the counter of a loop).

Comment: The counter of a loop isn't really an "object" though, I think the OP had something more complicated in mind.

Comment: @DavidTitarenco: As the term is defined in C and C++, yes, the counter of a loop most certainly *is* an object. The same can happen with more complex objects as well, of course.

Comment: And my point was that OP isn't using the C/C++ "object model" definition (found in §§1.8-1), he's using the OOP definition where an object is an instance of a class. It's not hard to deduce this, given his example.

Comment: @DavidTitarenco: The point is that you don't need to deduce it. Being an instance of a class or not is irrelevant.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to argue here. The OP did not mean "object" in the C/C++ sense, but rather in the OOP sense. Holding a loop counter in a register is trivially possible, a more complicated structure not so; hence, the question.

Comment: @DavidTitarenco: the point is that it *is* just as trivially possible for a structure such as he shows. Doing addition (for example) via a member function doesn't affect where the data gets stored.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, an object can live inside a processor's register if the object size is less than or equal to the size of the processor's register.

Whether or not the compiler chooses to do so is another matter.  Generate an assembly language listing.  Also, adjust the optimization levels as necessary.